# Why does the new C# 8 Index type start at the end from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

What is the reasoning behind the c# index type to index based on 1 when it's from the end?

`Index idx2 = ^3; // 3rd item from end`

So the above is the 3th element and not the 4th.
It's seems rather inconsistent to have it 1 based.

**EDIT**: The operator ^ for indexes is a new C# 8 Feature

Comment: [Hm](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-index-type2/) _Index idx1 = 2; // 3rd item. Array index starts at 0.  
    Index idx2 = ^3; // 3rd item from end_ So: __end__ is not the last element but the spot __after the last__ !!

Comment: because it makes sense, we can say the last one and get the last element by `A[^1]`

Comment: @HassanTareq But the first one is `A[0]`.

Comment: @GSerg array index is zero-based because compiler needs one less operation than one-based (i.e. row-major). So, `A[0]` and `A[^1]` are ok (in my opinion)